# Finding the quadrilateral with a fixed side and perimeter that has a maximum area

Tags: geometry, optimization

Given a quadrilateral *ABCD* with a fixed perimeter and the side *AD* having a fixed length
how can we prove that quadrilateral with maximum area satisfying the conditions above must also satisfy:

1. *$\angle$ABC = $\angle$BCD*
2. *AB = BC = CD*

For the second condition its straight forward. U can easily see that for any triangle. The triangles having the maximum are is the one where it’s isosceles (using ellipses)(or equilateral if you allowed all the sides to change accordingly) . Applying this for the points A , B , C and D its easy to see that the lengths of the sides of the quadrilateral must be equal.

The problem now boils down to the first condition
Any ideas on how proving it?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried maximizing the area of the parallelogram connecting the midpoints of the quadrilateral but it didn't help much

Comment: also prooving that AB = BC = CD is easy, all we have to do is consider the biggest area obtained by moving the points A,B,C and it turnes out that the figure with the maximum area must satisfy that all two adjacent sides must have the same length (ignoring the fixed side AD)

Comment: ABCD must also be concave.  The part where we have to prove that ∠ABC = ∠BCD is what bugging me

Comment: Not a proof. If one side is of zero length we have an equilateral triangle. Max area requires the additional non zero  side to be added inside a cyclic quadrilateral. With three sides equal in your reasoning only way the extra side is brought in is  with symmetry of isosceles triangle base angles being kept equal.

Comment: @Narasimham I understood what u mean but I'm having trouble understanding why must the quadrilateral be cyclic to ensure maximum area. Would u care to elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ABCD$ be the quadrilateral ($AB=BC=CD$) in its "equal angles" configuration (i.e. $BC\parallel AD$) and consider a small displacement $AB'C'D$ from that configuration
$(AB=AB'=B'C'=C'D)$: we want to prove that the area of $ABCD$ is greater than the area of $AB'C'D$. Let's suppose $B'$ and $C'$ are the result of a counterclockwise rotation of $B$ and $C$ about $A$ and $D$ respectively, as in figure below.

As $BB'\to 0$, segments $BB'$ and $CC'$ form the same angle with line $BC$; moreover, their projections on $BC$ must be equal (to ensure $B'C'=BC$). This implies that $BB'=CC'$ and that triangle $ABB'$ is congruent to triangle $DCC'$.

Hence the difference of the areas of quadrilaterals $ABCD$ and $AB'C'D$ is the same as the difference of the areas of triangles $MBB'$ and $MCC'$, where $M$ is the intersection point of $BC$ and $B'C'$. But these triangles have the same altitude upon bases $BM$ and $CM$, while $CM>BM$: it follows that the area of $MCC'$ is greater than the area of $MBB'$ and thus the area of $ABCD$ is greater than the area of $AB'C'D$, as it was to be proved.

[image]

EDIT.

The argument given above only proves that the "equal angles" configuration is a **local** maximum. To prove it is a global maximum one could use [Bretschneider's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider%27s_formula) for the area of a quadrilateral, which in our case gives:
$$
area = {1\over4}\sqrt{(a+d)^3(3a-d)-16a^3d\cos^2{\alpha+\gamma\over2}},
$$
where $a=AB=BC=CD$, $d=AD$, $\alpha=\angle DAB$ and $\gamma=\angle BCD$.

This formula obviously gives the maximum area when $\cos{\alpha+\gamma\over2}=0$, that is when $\alpha+\gamma=\pi$. But that condition implies the quadrilateral is cyclic and is then equivalent to $\angle ABC=\angle BCD$.

Comment: I have relized that the 3 sides must be because of a similar reasoning to the triangle but the same reasoning does not mean the angles must be equal too (i.e. angle ABC and angle BCD)

Comment: @Ak2399 You are right: I hadn't noticed your comment below the question. I completely rewrote my answer, trying to give a geometrical answer.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why must the segments BB′ and CC′ form the same angle with line BC

Comment: Because angles $\angle ABB'$ and $\angle DCC'$ tend to $90°$ as $BB'\to0$.

Comment: I don't see how this connects

Comment: If $\angle ABC=\angle BCD=\alpha$ then both $CC'$ and $BB'$ form an acute angle $|\alpha-\pi/2|$ with line $BC$.

Comment: so this would only work for small displacements. so if we considered a new small displacement  for AB'C'D to be AB''C''D counterclockwise, we can prove by similar arguments that the area of AB'C'D is greater than the area of AB"C"D? and conclude that ABCD has the largest area of all.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. I only proved that the initial configuration is a local maximum.

Comment: I added a proof which works globally.